I want make Bluetooth calling feature in Android App
If Phone A Having App A get a phone call it should be shown in Phone B having App B. Considering Both Phones are paired. How do I achieve this. I tried something. Is there any open source project for reference?
private fun listenForCallStateChanges() {
    val phoneStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
            when (state) {
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                        // Handle the incoming call state
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Incoming call from $phoneNumber",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        // Notify App B
                     sendMessageToAppB(phoneNumber)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "READ_PHONE_STATE permission not granted")
        }
    }


"I tried something" - and that something was ... what, exactly?
Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with relevant details, or it will likely be closed to due to insufficient details.

What does "it should be shown in Phone B" mean? I suggest that you edit your question and describe in detail what you are expecting App B on Phone B to do.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
